# thrust::device_vector of struct throw Bus Error

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

When attempting to create a `thrust::device_vector` of a `struct` I get a `Bus error (core dumped)`. The strange part is that the code below runs fine on my laptop (Quadro P2000). However, when I port this code on to a Jetson TX2 (tested in two different ones), the error shows up. I'm attaching a simple code that can reproduce this issue

`gpu_variable.h`

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>

class GpuFloat3Ptr {
 public:
  GpuFloat3Ptr() = delete;
  __host__ explicit GpuFloat3Ptr(float* cpu_float, size_t size);
  __host__ ~GpuFloat3Ptr();
  void useThrust(int num_points);

 protected:
  float3* var_;
  size_t size_;
};
```

`gpu_variable.cu`

```cpp
#include "gpu_variable.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

struct cloud_point_index_idx {
  unsigned int idx;
  float3 cloud_point;
  int instance;

  cloud_point_index_idx() = default;

  __host__ __device__
  cloud_point_index_idx(unsigned int idx_, float3 cloud_point_, int instance_) :
    idx(idx_), cloud_point(cloud_point_), instance(instance_) {}
};

GpuFloat3Ptr::GpuFloat3Ptr(float* cpu_float, size_t size) : size_(size) {
  cudaError_t cuda_stat = cudaMallocManaged(&var_, size);
  assert(cuda_stat == cudaSuccess);
  for (int i = 0; i < size / sizeof(float3); i++) {
    var_[i].x = cpu_float[3 * i];
    var_[i].y = cpu_float[3 * i + 1];
    var_[i].z = cpu_float[3 * i + 2];
  }
}

GpuFloat3Ptr::~GpuFloat3Ptr() {
  if (var_) cudaFree(var_);
}

void GpuFloat3Ptr::useThrust(int num_points) {
  thrust::device_vector<cloud_point_index_idx> voxel_idx_vector(num_points);
}
```

`main.cc`

```cpp
#include "gpu_variable.h"
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int number_points[] = {20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110};
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int cloud_size = number_points[i];
    std::cout << "Test " << cloud_size << " points in point cloud\n";
    float* myarray = new float[3*cloud_size];
    unsigned int seed(time(0));
    // Populate array
    for (int i = 0; i < 3 * cloud_size; i++) {
      myarray[i] = (rand_r(&seed) % 10 * 100) / 100.0;
    }
    GpuFloat3Ptr ptr(myarray, 3*cloud_size*sizeof(float));
    ptr.useThrust(cloud_size);
    delete[] myarray;
  }
}
```

```sh
$ nvcc -o test gpu_variable.cu main.cc 
$ ./test 
Test 20 points in point cloud
Test 30 points in point cloud
Bus error (core dumped)
```

The error happens when I call the `useThrust` function.

Comment: `delete myarray;` -- This is the wrong form of `delete`.  It should be `delete [] myarray;`.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed that part. (Problem still shows)

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < size / sizeof(float3); i++) ` -- Verify that the loop boundaries are correct.  You are passing in a hand-computed `size`, and hoping that dividing by `sizeof(float3)` yields a proper upper limit in the loop.  I've seen bugs occur because the programmer believes that computing sizes by doing `sizeof` coding gives correct results, when actually the result is wrong.

Comment: They are correct. Using `sizeof(float3)` or `3 * sizeof(float)` yield the same number. in the loop.

Comment: I'm basically asking if the bounds makes sense.  Whether they are equal to some other value isn't important.  If you know you're supposed to loop, say 10 times, but computing that value gives you 100, or 11 or 15, or whatever, then the computation is not correct.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't phrase my answer correctly. Yes, the boundaries are correct in what they are supposed to be. The variable `cloud_size` in `main.cc` matches `size / sizeof(float3)` in `gpu_variable.cu` which is what I'm expecting.

Comment: Basically you should be looking for low-hanging fruit that may be potential points of failure.  Issuing the wrong form of `delete []` was one.  The second is whether the loop overshoots the `var_` and `cpu_float` array boundaries, thus causing a memory overwrite.

Comment: Don't use managed memory. It is likely your are violating the managed memory usage constraints by mixing it with thrust -- instantiating a vector runs a kernel

Comment: Having said that, the example you posted runs without any error for me. But if you have a system using a different managed memory model, it might fail.

Comment: @talonmies Your advice was actually the issue. My question is, are there any guidelines to when we should use managed memory or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will answer my own question here. Thanks to @talonmies advice, the issue came from using managed memory. The TX2 has a different managed memory model that cause my code to fail. Using `cudaMalloc` instead of `cudaMallocManaged` fixed it.